# Cant undo vote?

Tags: support

Noticed this the first time today, appparently, if I vote for an answer, I cannot remove my vote unless the answer is changed.

Any reason behind that (and why not keep it the same as other SE sites?)

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75477/idea-behind-your-vote-is-now-locked-in-unless-this-answer-is-edited

Comment: If you notice that you were wrong downvoting (as it happened to me a few times), you can always ask the author to edit his/her post in order to be un-downvotable.

Comment: This does work the same as other SE sites, not sure what you're referring to in that last question.